# How long before a block hash is invalidated?

Tags: nearprotocol

The documentation says "Block hash is hash of the block from the current blockchain on top of which this transaction can be applied. It’s used to guard against blockchain forks and rollbacks."

If I try to sign and send a transaction with a block hash that is "a little out of date" then I get the error `InvalidTxError::Expired`

Is there some specific definition of this expiration timeout that I can use to predict whether it will happen and therefore need to refresh the block hash that I plan to use?

Does it happen after a period of time or if the block hash is Nth from the top of the chain or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a system-wide parameter `transaction_validity_period` that defines how long (for how many blocks) a transaction can be considered valid since the block hash it is based on.

Comment: PSA: the paramater `tx_validity_period` seems to be rarely used but `transaction_validity_period` appears often

Comment: Sorry my mistake. Should have double checked the exact name.

Answer (score 1):

after a little more digging based on @berryguy's accepted answer above, it looks like `transaction_validity_period` is an incoming parameter to `ChainGenesis` (pressing the blockchain start button, I guess) where the validity period is measured as a `BlockIndex` ("down from the top" or "back from the tip" of the chain depending on the animation playing out in your head)

[snip from nearcore source](https://github.com/nearprotocol/nearcore/blob/7cd0ab607edaa116dd93dfd3c97747ffc8bc8596/chain/chain/src/chain.rs#L149-L158)

```rust
pub struct ChainGenesis {
    pub time: DateTime<Utc>,
    pub gas_limit: Gas,
    pub gas_price: Balance,
    pub total_supply: Balance,
    pub max_inflation_rate: u8,
    pub gas_price_adjustment_rate: u8,
    pub transaction_validity_period: BlockIndex, /// <- here
    pub epoch_length: BlockIndex,
}
```

and gets populated by genesis configuration file `genesis.json` that's loaded from `~/.near/genesis.json` (on my local machine) maybe by a call to [`start_with_config`](https://github.com/nearprotocol/nearcore/blob/54b597cfc53de24aa7c9813eea87926ad9752aa1/near/src/lib.rs#L51)